# JVM Appears to be hung with Outofheapspace error while having response payload size more than 3 mb in Mule 4

Tags: jvm, mule, streaming, heap-memory, anypoint-studio

I am using mule 4 to retrieve records from database and show it in the response . Somehow I see all the components are getting passed successfully but while streaming the response its failing . I am trying to call from postman and I see error:

```
<h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>

The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
```

In the studio , I get logs like :
Pinging the JVM took 9 seconds to respond.
JVM appears hung: Timed out waiting for signal from JVM.  Requesting thread dump.
Dumping JVM state.
JVM appears hung: Timed out waiting for signal from JVM.  Restarting JVM.
JVM exited after being requested to terminate.
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped

Could anyone help me on this .

Thanks
Sanjukta

Answer (score 0):

Some information is not being streamed. You didn't provide any details of the implementation but clearly something is consuming a lot of heap memory. It may not be the database, but some other component. Check the streaming configuration for your components.

To identify the cause locally you can capture a heap dump and analyze it while the runtime in studio is timing out for the ping before it crashes. That is probably because of high garbage collection activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a symptom that your JVM heap memory is full, check your settings in Anypoint Studio and see how much is allocated

Check this article

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Out-Of-Memory-in-Studio-Application-How-to-increase-the-maximum-heap-size?r=6&ui-force-components-controllers-recordGlobalValueProvider.RecordGvp.getRecord=1